How to get the 'chess annotation symbols' into the \xskakloop
Is there a way to get the chess annotation symbols +, !, ?!, e.p., ....., with other words the  evaluations of chess moves, as written in the \mainline{...}, at the captions of a \xskakloop?

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\setchessboard{showmover=false, margin=false}

\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\mainline{% Zukertort – Blackburne (London 1883)
1. c2c4  e7e6 
2. e2e3 Ng8f6 
3. Ng1f3 b7b6 
4. Bf1e2 Bc8b7 
5. O-O d7d5 
6. d2d4 Bf8d6 
7. Nb1c3 O-O 
8. b2b3 Nb8d7 
9. Bc1b2 Qd8e7 
10. Nc3b5 Nf6e4 
11. Nb5xd6 c7xd6 
12. Nf3d2 Nd7f6 
13. f2f3 Ne4xd2 
14. Qd1xd2 d5xc4?!
15. Be2xc4 d6d5 
16. Bc4d3 Rf8c8
17. Ra1e1 Rc8c7?!   
18. e3e4 Ra8c8
19. e4e5 Nf6e8
20. f3f4 g7g6
21. Re1e3!   f7f5
22. e5xf6!\,e.p.  Ne8xf6 % set e.p. with a space
23. f4f5!  Nf6e4 
%24. Bd3xe4 d5xe4
%25. f5xg6! Rc7c2
%26. g6xh7+ Kg8h8
%27. d4d5+ e6e5
%28. Qd2b4!   Rc8c5
%29. Rf1f8+   Kh8xh7
%30. Qb4xe4+ Kh7g7 
%31. Bb2xe5+  Kg7xf8
%32. Be5g7+!  Kf8g8 
%33. Qe4xe7
}

\noindent\xskakloop[step=1]{%%
\begin{tabular}{c}
\chessboard[tinyboard,
setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]
\\
\xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{lan}%
\rule{0pt}{5mm} \\[0.5em]%
\end{tabular}\hspace{4mm}}%%
\end{document}


If you want to have comments, you can simply add them, as in the following example:
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\setchessboard{showmover=false, margin=false}

\begin{document}
\newchessgame

\mainline{% Zukertort – Blackburne (London 1883)
1. c2c4  e7e6 
2. e2e3 Ng8f6 
3. Ng1f3 b7b6 
4. Bf1e2 Bc8b7 
5. O-O d7d5 
6. d2d4 Bf8d6 
7. Nb1c3 O-O 
8. b2b3 Nb8d7 
9. Bc1b2 Qd8e7 
10. Nc3b5 Nf6e4 
11. Nb5xd6 c7xd6 
12. Nf3d2 Nd7f6 
13. f2f3 Ne4xd2 
14. Qd1xd2 d5xc4?!
15. Be2xc4 d6d5 
16. Bc4d3 Rf8c8
17. Ra1e1 Rc8c7?!   
18. e3e4 Ra8c8
19. e4e5 Nf6e8
20. f3f4 g7g6
21. Re1e3!   f7f5
22. e5xf6!\,e.p.  Ne8xf6 % set e.p. with a space
23. f4f5!  Nf6e4 
%24. Bd3xe4 d5xe4
%25. f5xg6! Rc7c2
%26. g6xh7+ Kg8h8
%27. d4d5+ e6e5
%28. Qd2b4!   Rc8c5
%29. Rf1f8+   Kh8xh7
%30. Qb4xe4+ Kh7g7 
%31. Bb2xe5+  Kg7xf8
%32. Be5g7+!  Kf8g8 
%33. Qe4xe7
}



\noindent\xskakloop[step=1]{%%
\begin{tabular}{c}
\chessboard[tinyboard,
setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]
\\
%\xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{lan}%
\xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{lan}\xskakget{comments}% here - PS
\rule{0pt}{5mm} \\[0.5em]%
\end{tabular}\hspace{4mm}}%%
\end{document}

Below there is the second page of chessboards, including moves 14 and 17:

The side effect is that in move 22 you obtain e.p. twice. But it is enough to write \renewcommand\xskakenpassanttext{} before  \xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{lan}\xskakget{comments}.
